# Linking the Sql Database to Excel using a query

Tags: sql, database, excel, import

I am trying to bring data from SQL server using a Microsoft query the result is displayed correctly in the preview but once I close the Microsoft query window and apply it to the sheet I get the error: "problem obtaining data" if I pull it as a pivot table ...and it doesn't populate if I pull it as a table it just writes "Query from Data_Source" in the selected field and runs the query in the background and stays as is when that's finished instead of showing me the table result. 
[pivot table error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZutM.png)
[table pull error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueiCd.png)

can anyone please help me figure out what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: How many rows are there in your result set? more than 65536?

Comment: What Excel version?

Comment: Can you show use the query and a view of the preview. Previews generally only show the Top 200 or 1000 records, so the problem may be after that window.

Comment: Excel 2010 and the result set is 2800 rows only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the Query into a Stored procedure, it is working well now, Thank for the help !